# Fullscreen application

Tags: c++, qt, unity-game-engine

Im writing an application on Qt 5. I have transparent window and i want to make it full screen. So, how im doing that:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent): QMainWindow(parent) {
    setStyleSheet("background: #000;");
    setWindowOpacity(0.82);
    setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
    showFullScreen();
}
```

But now when application starts system panel disappears.
Here is screenshot:

[image]

So, can i make panel to stay put?

Comment: didn't you mean maximized? It should span the whole screen but leave the system panel intact.

Comment: No, i need exactly full screen with system panel.

Comment: you didn't paste in your screenshot correctly.

Comment: Also, try getting rid of your window flags. In fullscreen mode, those settings would be redundant anyway. They may be doing something unexpected.

Comment: You dont see screenshot? //i tried to remove flags, it didnt helped

Comment: What is the "system panel" here? If you mean the system's task bar with the start button, ..., showFullScreen does hide that.

Comment: Ok, so, can i create app which will be full screen and will not hide task bar?

Comment: Yes, if you make it maximized with no frame.

Comment: It doesn't overlap taskbar when i do that.

Comment: You really need to specify that in your question. See Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the header `<QScreen>` to get the display size, and size your window accordingly.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent): QMainWindow(parent) {
    setStyleSheet("background: #000;");
    setWindowOpacity(0.82);
    setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
    setFixedSize(QGuiApplication::primaryScreen()->size());
}
```

Linux users will probably be able to move the window using alt+click, however.